How can I create table on remote database along with constraints(not null, default and primary key) using jdbc in pyspark?
I was able to create table by using the below code but unable to find the solution with constraints.
df.write \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", "id INT, name VARCHAR(29)") \
    .jdbc(oracle_url, "demoTable", mode='overwrite' ,properties=oracleProperties)

